# Using wordpress and plugins with composer

Tags: wordpress, composer-php

Summarized: how do I use WordPress with Composer, when some plugins use composer already and have their own libraries?

I am using roots/bedrock (adjusted to my needs with other wordpress folder and some dependencies removed, which I don't need), the problem I see is that when I install plugins over wordpress (e.g. MailPoet or WP SMTP) it seems that these plugins have their own vendor folders and autoloader (which means they already use composer by themselves)

This is my adjusted `composer.json` (does not really differ from the original)

```
{
  "name": "roots/bedrock",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "WordPress boilerplate with modern development tools, easier configuration, and an improved folder structure",
  "homepage": "https://roots.io/bedrock/",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Scott Walkinshaw",
      "email": "scott.walkinshaw@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/swalkinshaw"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben Word",
      "email": "ben@benword.com",
      "homepage": "https://github.com/retlehs"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "bedrock", "composer", "roots", "wordpress", "wp", "wp-config"
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues",
    "forum": "https://discourse.roots.io/category/bedrock"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "composer/installers": "^1.4",
    "roots/wordpress": "5.2.2",
    "roots/wp-password-bcrypt": "1.0.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/app/mu-plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-muplugin"],
      "web/app/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"],
      "web/app/themes/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-theme"]
    },
    "wordpress-install-dir": "web"
  }
}
```

There are no error messages, but I am worried of the redundancy happening, that my complete wordpress structure has an autoloader and vendor/ folder, the same thing happens in almost every plugin again. How should I structure the code and work with this?

Comment: You're installing these plugins via WordPress GUI or using `composer require`?

Comment: I am installing the plugins via `Plugins -> Add new`
Not all plugins are available via Composer, nor the latest versions

Comment: All WP plugins should be available through https://wpackagist.org/ (you already have it in your repositories).

Comment: Installing through wpackagist is the same as through the gui. Dependancies are still redundant (e.g. vendor/)

Comment: Yeah, but with composer you will be able to fork and patch these plugins to use one global vendor and one version of every dependency. With using GUI and oficial repositories you can just wait for conflicts and pray that it will never happen.

Comment: `you will be able to fork and patch these plugins` <- how is this done? to patch `vendor/` directories

Comment: You can fork plugin repo and use `repositories` config in `composer.json` to use this fork repo instead of original package.